# Performing sql query on button click

Tags: php, mysql

I had design a form and value of form are showing in table format.In table i have two columns which are buttons Edit and Delete respectively.I want to perform update and delete query on that buttons where id is first column in my table.
here is code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Unable to create to connection");
mysql_select_db("sunil") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $Id= $_POST["id"];
    $Name1=$_POST["t1"];
    $Name2=$_POST["t2"];
    $Sex=$_POST["sex"];
    $Country=$_POST["Country"];
    $Hobby=$_POST["check"];
    $Email=$_POST["t3"];
    $Pass=$_POST["p1"];
    $Repass=$_POST["p2"];
    $sql="INSERT INTO registration (Your_id,First_Name,Last_Name,Sex,Country,Hobbies,Email,Password,Repassword) VALUES('$Id','$Name1','$Name2','$Sex','$Country','$Hobby','$Email','$Pass','$Repass')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration");
print "<table border=1>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>".$row['Your_id']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['First_Name']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Last_Name']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Sex']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Country']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Hobbies']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
        echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="return update()"></td>'; 
// tell me code of update()
        echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="DELETE FROM registration WHERE Your_id=id"></td>'; 
// tell me what to use in place of is in this line
        print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";
?>

And here is snap shot
[1]: http://sunilpachlangia.blogspot.in/2013/11/blog-post.html
```

Comment: than what is the problem?

Comment: Both Queries are not working.....

Comment: javascript can't running your sql query, you have to use ajax, so that you request for the delete query to another php file with unique id.

Comment: I am not using javascript where is my mistake in code

Comment: `onclick="DELETE FROM registration WHERE Your_id=id"` and `onclick="return update()"`

Comment: I know that is an error now tell me how can i correct it

Answer (score 0):

```
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>".$row['Your_id']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['First_Name']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['Last_Name']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['Sex']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['Country']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['Hobbies']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
    echo '<td><a href="req=update&id=UNIQUE_ID">edit</a>'; 
    echo '<td><a href="req=delete&id=UNIQUE_ID">delete</a>'; 
    print "</tr>";
```

Now on the starting of the page check for the Request:

```
if( isset($_GET['req']) ){
    switch($_GET['req']){
        case 'update':
           // Get the Unique ID
           // and perform your update query with update form
        break;
        case 'delete':
           // Get the Unique ID
           // and perform your delete query
        break;
    }
}
```

I give you a basic idea how you can achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by Get Unique ID

Comment: when i write DELETE query it gives error like                      Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FROM' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sunil